# Why is the webview screen out of the device area when I'm constrained?

Tags: ios, swift, webview, storyboard, wkwebview

I am a beginner `iOS` developer. My problem is that when I put constraints, the `webview` screen is out of the device area. I'm currently using the storyboard based on the `iPhone 8`. So this is happening on the `iPhone SE`. It works well when I set `AutoResize`. However, the constraint leaves the device area. What's the problem? If you don't include any constraints, Warning remains. I want to remove it.

**AutoResize** It's work!!!!

[image]

**constraints** It's not work!!!!

[image]

[image]

What am I missing? I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: In what direction does the view go out of the screen? Try to set the top constraint to safe area instead of Superview.

Comment: @DinuNicolae The screen on the right is cropped.